# Pi 3A+ doesn't boot past rc-local.service - how can I fix this on Windows?

Tags: boot-issues, software-installation

Just set up my first Pi for the first time using a Windows computer - I don't have another Linux system available to me. I got the Pi working by flashing the Raspian disk image onto the SD, and this booted fine.

I have an Adafruit screen which I installed using the instructions on [this page](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/easy-install-2) and VNC. (Not sure that this is relevant - just including it for completeness' sake.) When that installation prompted me to reboot, I did so, and now the Pi doesn't progress past "rc-local.service" when booting and doesn't reach the desktop.

I was able to edit a cmdline.txt in the SD card on Windows and open a shell immediately on boot before logging in as per [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=37958#p315062). From there I was able to `vi /etc/rc.local` and see that the screen installation had indeed changed the file (but not by me). I was not able to edit it as the system was in read-only mode.

Given that I only have a Windows system to work with, how can I remedy this? If that solution is just to start from scratch, how can I prevent it from happening?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you do anything with `/etc/rc.local`? Do you edited it and inserted lines for starting programs at boot?

Comment: @Ingo I did not. I was able to edit a cmdline.txt in the SD card on Windows and open a shell immediately on boot before logging in as per [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=37958#p315062). From there I was able to `vi /etc/rc.local` and see that the screen installation had indeed changed the file. I was not able to edit it as the system was in read-only mode. So to answer your question, yes, rc.local had been changed (but not by me)

Comment: Basically attempting to install old code on a new model Pi is futile. The code doesn't claim to work on the 3B+ or 3A+. In particular attempting to install obsolete images without support for current firmware is unlikely to work.

Comment: "The code doesn't claim to work on the 3B+ or 3A+" where are you reading this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the script you have used to setup the screen is a bit outdated. You should use another installation procedure.

If you have booted the RasPi for disaster recovery into `init=/bin/sh` from `cmdline.txt` then you can remount the root filesystem read/write with `mount -n -o remount,rw /`. Now fix the entries in `/etc/rc.local`. B.t.w. other users of MS Windows are often use a live CD from Debian or Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution for troubleshooting. They just boot their MS Windows computer with it. Then you can access the `ext4` root partition on the SD Card and can do other Linux like things.